# CTA method in playable ad for Mintegral platform

Tags: google-ads-api, facebook-ads-api, unityads, applovin, ironsource

I made a playable ad and now i want to make a build for Mintegral platform. As the whole point of playable ad is to redirect user to store, i need to implement a CTA (call to action) method, that will do so. Every platform requires specific code to redirect user to store. And there is no much information about minegral code requirements. I found this recomendation on their website:
The whole process of the playable needs a button for directing to Store, in order to make sure a button labeled “Download Now” can be shown all the time through the game and direct to Store. All features that direct to App Store must call API

```
window.install && window.install();
```

Is it all i hve to do for cta method? there is no specific url. May be i need to assign a url in their dashboard, not in the playable itself?

i tried to implenent this code as a cta method, but mintegral playable test site(https://www.mindworks-creative.com/review/) does not detect my method as a cta method.

```
onClick: function (store) {
        window.install && window.install();
           if (store === undefined)
               store = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") > -1 ? "google" : "apple";
   
           var urls = {
               "google": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my id",
               "apple": "https://apps.apple.com/us/app/my id"
           };
           var url = urls[store];
           mraid.open(url);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what working for us

```
this.url = your.url

const mindWorksCallback = () => {
    window.gameEnd && window.gameEnd();
    window.install ? window.install() : window.top.open(this.url);
    console.log('openStore', window);
};
```

and then in playable we put this callback on download btn